# Proving Characteristic Subgroups are Transitive

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group, characteristic-subgroups

I know this is exactly the same as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200704/being-characteristic-is-transitive) question. But the proof detailed uses restrictions, and I'm not familiar with that. The way I want to prove this is by the standard method of showing two sets are equal since both $\phi(G)$ and $G$ are both sets correct?

If we have groups $N,K,G$ where $N \leq K \leq G$. 
Given: 
 $\phi(N) = N$ $\forall \phi \in Aut(K)$ 
$\phi(K) = K$ $\forall \phi \in Aut(G)$ 
Show: 
$\phi(N) = N$ $\forall \phi \in Aut(G)$

First we pick $x \in \phi(N)$ and show $x \in N$ where $\phi: G \rightarrow G$ is an automorphism.

However, this is where I'm not sure what to do. Am I even on the right track here?

Comment: Maybe try looking up what restrictions are before dismissing them. I'm not sure there's a solution that doesn't use them.

Comment: I don't seem to think that saying "I'm not familiar with that" implies that he is dismissing them (i.e. treating them as unworthy of serious consideration)

Comment: @jgon He doesn't dismiss them, but as the answer is not clear so when he doesn't understand it, he thinks it's because he doesn't familiar with the notation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe let's just talk through why restrictions is the way to go.

Suppose we have $\phi\colon G \to G$ an automorphism. We want to show that $\phi(N) = N$. Since $K$ is characteristic, we know that $\phi(K) = K$. Now consider the map $\varphi\colon K \to K$ defined by $\varphi(k) = \phi(k)$. Since $\phi(K) = K$, we see that $\varphi$ is surjective. I'll leave you to check that $\varphi$ is injective and a homomorphism. What we've shown then, is that $\varphi$ is an automorphism of $K$, so since $N$ is characteristic in $K$, we see that $\varphi(N) = N$. This tells us that $$\text{for every }x \in N,\ \varphi(x) = \phi(x) \in N.$$

Therefore we conclude that $\phi(N) = N$.

Actually, if you've done your exercise, you've shown something a little more: $\varphi$ is exactly what we mean by restriction: $\phi|_K$ means look at what happens if we forget about what $\phi$ does to group elements outside of $K$. Since $K$ is a subgroup, you've shown that $\phi|_K$ is still a homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your frustration, I also read several proofs but hard to understand them because somehow and I don't know why they all seem to omit the most important part of the explanation.

First about restriction notation, it's easy to understand and a neat thing write. So instead of writing:

$\phi(N) = N$ $\forall \phi \in Aut(K)$

It could be written as:

$\phi|_K(N) = N$

So we are going to use this notation to prove that if $N \: char \: K \: char \: G$ then $N \: char \: G$.

Let $\phi \in Aut(G)$, so $\phi(K) = K$ since $K$ is characteristic in $G$.

Now please note the most important part of the proof. If we have $\varphi \in Aut(K)$ we will also have $\varphi(K) = K$, so it's no difference than $\phi(K) = K$ as there is all the elements of $Aut(K)$ in $Aut(G)$. In other words:

> $\varphi(K) = \phi(K) = K$.

Note that $\varphi$ could be written in restriction notation as $\phi|_K(K) = K$, it's the same thing because $\phi|_K \in Aut(K)$. So we could rewrite the above equality as:

> $\phi|_K(K) = \phi(K) = K$.

( So we don't have to define a new symbol such $\varphi$ every time. )

As $N \: char \: K$, we have the same relationship between $N$ and $K$ as following:

> $\phi|_N(N) = \phi|_K(N) = N$.

But we have had that $\phi|_K(K) = \phi(K)$, or is all there elements of $Aut(K)$ in $Aut(G)$, including $N < K$, so we have $\phi|_K(N) = \phi(N)$. Combine them all, we have:

> $\phi|_N(N) = \phi|_K(N) = \phi(N) = N$.

Which is by definition $N \: char \: G$.