# Turning my short sloppy proof that $G \blacktriangleright H \blacktriangleright K$ then $G \blacktriangleright K$ into a concise and neat proof?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, characteristic-subgroups

Continuing to work on writing clean proofs while studying for a qualifying exam (1st try as I enter grad school so there are no stakes involved). I can "see" the rationale for the titular proof in my head and can explain it (sort of) in words but I'm at a loss for the cleanest and most concise way to write it out. Here's my attempt...

> $\mathbf{Theorem}$:  group $G$, and subgroups $H$ and $K$ which form a
>   "chain" of characteristic subgroups $G \blacktriangleright H 
> > \blacktriangleright K$ show that $G \blacktriangleright K$.
>
> $\mathbf{Proof}$: The groups of automorphisms on $G, H$, and $K$ are
>   denoted as $\operatorname{Aut}(G), \operatorname{Aut}(H)$, and
>   $\operatorname{Aut}(K)$ respectively.
>
> Every element has $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ is "embedded" in some
>   element of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ because $H$ is characteristic in
>   $G$.
>
> Similarly every element of $\operatorname{Aut}(K)$ is "embedded" in
>   some element of $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$.
>
> Since $K \blacktriangleleft H$ we have every element of
>   $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ has some element of $\operatorname{Aut}(K)$
>   embedded in it.
>
> Smiilarly, since $H \blacktriangleleft G$ we have every element of
>   $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ has some element of $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$
>   embedded in it.
>
> Clearly we have that every automorphism of $G$ has an automorphism of
>   $K$ embeded in it. Hence $K \blacktriangleleft G$, $\square$.

$\mathbf{Self Critique}$: I believe that speaking of "embedding" without being very clear about what that means is a problem but am unsure how to flesh it out for precision's sake (and possibly that might make this proof inaccurate?)

It was suggested that this is a duplicate of [Being characteristic is transitive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200704/being-characteristic-is-transitive) which it is not. This question is tagged as "proof-writing" as in I needed feedback in writing a better version of my own proof and not simply copying another person's proof.

Comment: You could speak instead of "fixing".  "Any automorphism of $G$ fixes $H$.", for instance.

Comment: When you write "every element of $\text{Aut}(K)$ is 'embedded' in some element of $\text{Aut}(H)$", what this *seems* to mean is that for every element $f \in \text{Aut}(K)$ there exists an element $g \in \text{Aut}(H)$ such that for every $x \in K$ we have $f(x)=g(x)$. Is that what you intended? If so, I worry that it is false (and unnecessary ... see the answer of @EricTowers).

Comment: Duplicate of [Being characteristic is transitive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200704/being-characteristic-is-transitive)

Comment: Before you ask a question, try to check if it's been asked before. (Many of your recent questions have been answered before.)

Comment: @verret I already knew the question was correct (yes the theorem is true) and I wanted specific feedback on my proof attempt to help me write better proofs. I feel like this suggestion is well meaning but not relevant to a question tagged "proof-writing"

Comment: @AlgebraisAwesome, why did you use this odd notation with a black triangle? If $H$ is a characteristic subgroup of $K$, then we write $H char K$ in group theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any automorphism of $G$ fixes $H$.  Any automorphism of $G$, restricted to $H$, is an automorphism of $H$.  Any automorphism of $H$ fixes $K$, so any automorphism of $G$ fixes $K$.  Therefore $K$ is characteristic in $G$.

Comment: Isn't the word "fixes" ambiguous to say $\sigma(H)\subset H$  ?

Comment: @reuns, but it is equivalent to say that every automorphism fixes $H$ and that $H$ is invariant under every automorphism. One direction is obvious, for other apply invariance of the inverse automorphism.

Comment: No I mean "mapped to itself" is not the same as "fixed by"

Comment: @reuns : One can distinguish "fixes elementwise" and "fixes setwise".  Without the modifier it is setwise.

Comment: @reuns, ok I get you. But you can look at $\operatorname{Aut}G$ acting on $G$ and acting on its subgroups to get both meanings of "fixes".

Comment: Thank you! Along with the comments this is a very helpful response. I will wait a couple hours before I select an answer to encourage others to try their hand at it.